# CSS image resizing (using width and hight) differs in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, resize, width

I'm a bit confused. I try to resize an image using CSS. While in Safari and Chrome the image resizes, in IE and Firefox it keeps it's original size but crops. What do I need to change to have it resized in FF and IE as well?
CSS looks as follows:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#image1 {
    background-image: url(img/myimage.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 532px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

and the body:

```
<body> <div id='image1'></div> </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried your code in Firefox (17.0.1 -- OSX).

With and without

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

the image actually resizes as expected.

You sould check for typos in your CSS I guess.

Comment: dude, you saved my day! :-) I forgot to declare the doctype. Now it works on all browsers. Didn't work on the newest FF version without <!DOCTYPE html>, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a % or px in

```
background-size: 100% 100;
```

I've tested [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hh5Mn/) in Chrome, IE, and Firefox with good results. I also added no-repeat in case there is a need to scale smaller images up.

Comment: Thanks. The % is there. I edited my post above. I tried the no-repeat as well. Unfortunately, the result remains the same unfortunately. I even tried with the very same image link you used (http://lorempixel.com/600/600). Chromes stretches the image while Firefox just crops it.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the background position fixed, and then add this to your html.

`<img src="img/myimage.png" alt="background image" id="image1" />`